# Raster to polygon script loop failing!! error 99999!

Tags: python, esri, arcmap

I am trying to make a script which selects every .png file in a folder beginning with the letters "LG". I then want the scipt create a shapefile, replacing the "LG" with "SH", and then i want the script to buffer that shapefile and rename the buffer with the first 2 letters being "SB"!

I keep getting an error 99999 error message at line 37!

```
( gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(INPUT_RASTER, Output_polygon_features, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE") )
```

Can anyone see why this isnt working? I am very, very new to this and have been staring at this script pulling out my hair for days!!

Here is the script:

```
# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Conversion Tools.tbx")
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Analysis Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...

folder = "D:\\J04-0083\\IMAGEFILES"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder): # returms root, dirs, and files
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]

        try:
            first_2_letters = filename_zero[0] + filename_zero[1]
        except:
            first_2_letters = "XX"

        if first_2_letters == "LG":
            Output_polygon_features = "D:\\J04-0083\\ShapeFiles.gdb\\" + "SH_" + filename + ".shp"

            # Process: Raster to Polygon...

            INPUT_RASTER = os.path.join(root + "\\" + filename_zero + ".png")
            gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(INPUT_RASTER, Output_polygon_features, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE") 

            Distance__value_or_field_ = "5 Meters"
            Raster_Buffer_shp = "SB_" + filename + ".shp"

            # Process: Buffer...
            gp.Buffer_analysis(Output_polygon_features, Raster_Buffer_shp, Distance__value_or_field_, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "")
```

Comment: its not excitement it is "staring at a script which doesn't work for 3 days" induced madness (!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Is .png the format that this function wants? PNG is a compressed format so I would think that something like this would be expecting an uncompressed format. In fact, since the name of the function is RasterToPolygon_conversion, wouldn't the function be expecting a [raster format](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Supported_raster_dataset_file_formats)? The [docs](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/conversion_tools/raster_to_polygon_conversion_.htm) say that the input should be an `integer raster dataset`. In addition, `The input raster can have any cell size and may be any valid integer raster dataset.` Anyway, I suspect that is the real problem.

The last thing to check, if the file is in the correct format as per above, is if there is a field `VALUE` in the file.

Comment: This is the new error i am getting! But when i run the functions manually in ArcMap i dont get any errors - hence the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

try using a GRID or TIFF file instead of a PNG.
You can convert the PNG with: 
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=raster_to_other_format_(multiple)_(conversion)

and then process it's output into the Raster to Polygon conversion.

You could also check the file path of the INPUT RASTER to make sure it looks correct by:

```
INPUT_RASTER = os.path.join(root + "\\" + filename_zero + ".png")
print INPUT_RASTER
gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(INPUT_RASTER, Output_polygon_features, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE")
```

There is also a method of building a filepath by:

```
import os
root + os.sep + filename_zero + '.png'
```